# color block of text without repeatedly using /textcolor

Tags: math-mode, color

I want to color the answers into blue however my current solution is not really viable as each line needs to be colored blue individually due to my use of `\par\bigskip` messes up `\textcolor` if its in the command ie:

```
\textcolor{blue}{$ =\frac{6}{3}$} \par\bigskip
     $ = 2$ }
```

returns errors, (I don't even think this is the most efficient way to achieve what i want either but its the only way I can think of)

Here is my source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, paperwidth=992pt, paperheight=1450pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} 1.]
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\item Simplify the following:
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} (a),labelsep=5mm,itemsep=0.5\baselineskip,leftmargin=*]
    \item $ \frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{3}$ \par\bigskip
    \textcolor{blue}{$ =\frac{6}{3}$} \par\bigskip
    \textcolor{blue}{ $ = 2$ }


    \item  $ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}$ \par\bigskip
    \textcolor{blue}{$ =\frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{4}$ }\par\bigskip
    \textcolor{blue}{$ =\frac{3}{4}$}

    \item $ \frac{4}{3} + \frac{2}{5}$ \par\bigskip
    \textcolor{blue}{ $ =\frac{20}{15} + \frac{6}{15}$ }\par\bigskip
    \textcolor{blue}{ $ =\frac{26}{15}$}

    \item $ \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{8}{12} + \frac{3}{12}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{11}{12}$

    \item $ \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{23}{10}$

    \item $ \frac{5}{6} + \frac{2}{3}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{5}{6} + \frac{4}{6}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{9}{6}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered trying an math environment for equations instead, e.g. `\textcolor{blue}{
 \begin{align*}
       &= \frac{6}{3} \\
       &= 2
       \end{align*}}`

Comment: they are already in a math environment denoted by the $'s just shorthand to save space.

Comment: Yes, and it forces you those awkward `\par\bigskip` commands ;-)

Comment: haha makes sense! i ended up using werners code which doesn't use $ :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an automated way of handling the question/answer part of every entry:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, paperwidth=992pt, paperheight=1450pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol,array,collcell,stix}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\formatQandA}[1]{\ifnum\value{QandA}>1 \color{answercolor}\fi\displaystyle{}#1}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\stepcounter{QandA}\collectcell\formatQandA}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcounter{QandA}
\newenvironment{QandA}
  {\setcounter{QandA}{0}% Start with row 0
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}% Stretch out array vertically
   $\array[t]{@{}L}}
  {\endarray$}
\colorlet{answercolor}{blue}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} 1.]
  \item Simplify the following:
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} (a),labelsep=5mm,itemsep=0.5\baselineskip,leftmargin=*]
      \item \begin{QandA}
        \frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{3} \\
        = \frac{6}{3} \\
        = 2
      \end{QandA}

      \item \begin{QandA}
        \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \\
        = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{4} \\
        = \frac{3}{4}
      \end{QandA}

      \item \begin{QandA}
        \frac{4}{3} + \frac{2}{5} \\
        = \frac{20}{15} + \frac{6}{15} \\
        = \frac{26}{15}
      \end{QandA}

      \item \begin{QandA}
        \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \\
        = \frac{8}{12} + \frac{3}{12} \\
        = \frac{11}{12}
      \end{QandA}

      \item \begin{QandA}
        \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2} \\
        = \frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10} \\
        = \frac{23}{10}
      \end{QandA}

      \item \begin{QandA}
        \frac{5}{6} + \frac{2}{3} \\
        = \frac{5}{6} + \frac{4}{6} \\
        = \frac{9}{6}
      \end{QandA}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The contents of the `QandA` environment collects every cell and either sets it using a color or not. The condition is based on whether you're in the first row the environment or not. First row is considered the question (and is therefore set in black/default) while subsequent rows are set in color `answercolor` (let to `blue`).

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question you can us `\color{blue}` and put it in a group so its effect does not continue past the group:

[image]

However, I would highly recommend you instead define a custom environment that simplifies the entry of the desired output. Whenever you have a lot of manually inserted spacing it is time to rethink things.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, paperwidth=992pt, paperheight=1450pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} 1.]
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\item Simplify the following:
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} (a),labelsep=5mm,itemsep=0.5\baselineskip,leftmargin=*]
    \item $ \frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{3}$ \par\bigskip
    {\color{blue} $ =\frac{6}{3}$ \par\bigskip
    $ = 2$}


    \item  $ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}$ \par\bigskip
    {\color{blue}$ =\frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{4}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{3}{4}$}

    \item $ \frac{4}{3} + \frac{2}{5}$ \par\bigskip
    {\color{blue} $ =\frac{20}{15} + \frac{6}{15}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{26}{15}$}

    \item $ \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{8}{12} + \frac{3}{12}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{11}{12}$

    \item $ \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{23}{10}$

    \item $ \frac{5}{6} + \frac{2}{3}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{5}{6} + \frac{4}{6}$ \par\bigskip
    $ =\frac{9}{6}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you quickly tell me how to define a custom environment, i'm pretty new at latex

Comment: @user1448093: Looks like Werner has already provided such an environment.  Personally I would have done it slightly differently as I don't consider the intermediate steps as the answer.